# I'm trying to do remember me feature at login page using django built-in auth view

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        # print(self.get_initial(),'--------1')
        return kwargs
    
    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.POST:
            if self.request.POST.get('remember'):
                self.request.session['usernameS'] = self.request.POST['username']
                self.request.session['passwordS'] = self.request.POST['password']
                self.request.session['remember'] = True
        self.initial = {
            'username':self.request.session.get('usernameS'),
            'password':self.request.session.get('passwordS'),
            'remember':self.request.session.get('remember')
            }
        print(self.initial)
        return self.authentication_form or self.form_class
```

#### But whenever I logged out it's not showing initial values and {'username': None, 'password': None, 'remember': None}

Comment: **Don't** store credentials / passwords in your session! The correct way to implement a feature like you want is to set [`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age). Also why your solution doesn't work ("_But whenever I logged out_") is because obviously the session is cleared when you logout... Also wait by "remember me" you mean remember the user even _after_ they logout and prefill the form with their credentials!! That is a massive security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

It shows `None` because you have initialized your form where the initial values are `None` itself, to rectify this just do a slight change in your `self.initial` dictionary

```
self.initial = {
    'username':self.request.session.get('usernameS') or '',
    'password':self.request.session.get('passwordS') or '',
    'remember':self.request.session.get('remember') or False,
}
```